# Symfony event vs service

Tags: symfony, events, service

Hi I have a question about symfony application architecture,
In my application I create different user, but when a user is created, updated, deleted, or his picture change, I need to do some action.

What is the best way to do this ? I excluded to do this on a controller action. There is 2 others solutions :

- Create differents events like user.created, user.updated, ... And dispatch it on the controller action and make different listener to do the different action like MailListener (for user.created) TaskListener (for user.created) for add a task.
- Use a service like UserManager and on this service have a method like userCreated() and on this method call differents actions like sendMailOnCreated, addTaskOnCreated for example.

For you what is the best method ?

Comment: As usual the answer is: it depends.  An event based system is very flexible.  If you need to do something else on user.create then you can just plugin another listener.  On the other hand, a user manager lets you bring all the functionality together in one place and might be easier to maintain.  My inclination is to use events but there is no "best" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your first solution is the best one. It's clearly a use case for the Event component. It will be easier to maintain and more readable.

Moreover, if you need to add more listener you just need to create another one and bind it to your event. You don't need to modify your controller anymore.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be easier to maintain or more readable. In the end you would replace the event emit with a method call, nothing else. Therefore unit testing events is more difficult I think than just using a normal service. If the above application is not a bundle, which shouldn't be used from 3rd party, then I would stick with the service solution.